# how to add templatefield or Column dynamically in gridview in asp.net c# when auto generated column property is false

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to add template-field or Column dynamically in grid view in asp.net c# when auto generated column property is false ?

```
// <asp:TextBox ID="colmtst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   //<asp:Button ID="crtcolm" runat="server" Text="Add Column" 
       // onclick="crtcolm_Click" />
```

Add column with text box value in grid view on button click event .

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Some thing Like THis

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="False">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
                            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" runat="server" Width="100%"
                            EmptyDataText="No Records to Display." AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selected" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr. No.">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="50px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductCode" HeaderText="Code"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                                    DataFormatString="{0:0,0.00}"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Latest">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#Eval("Latest").ToString()=="True"?"Yes":"No" %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>



                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```